# Decoding the encoded response

Tags: json, wso2, httprequest, wso2-micro-integrator

I am unable to figure out how can I decode and encoded response. I am getting when I hit and endpoint in wso2.

This is the response I am getting:

```
{"binary":"eyJSZXNwb25zZUluZm8iOiB7CiAgICAgICAgIlJlc3VsdENvZGUiOiAyMDAsCiAgICAgICAgIlJlc3VsdERlc2MiOiAic3VjY2VzcyIKICAgICAgfQp9"}
```

This is the response I should get

```
{"ResponseInfo": {
        "ResultCode": 200,
        "ResultDesc": "success"
      }
}
```

When I decode the code starting from "eyJSZXN" I get the correct payload. So only issue is that I am unable to convert it to json when I am fetching it.

```
    <call>
       <endpoint key="Endpoint"/>
    </call>
   <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>           
   <property expression="json-eval($)" name="ResponseJSON" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

The above code gives me the binary response in ResponseJSON. Hence, I would request if anyone can help me with this issue please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `base64Decode` function for this. Check the following example.

```xml
<property name="encodedBody" expression="json-eval($.binary)"/>
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>$1</format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="base64Decode($ctx:encodedBody)"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```